# how to set header username and password in mule

Tags: mule

```
 <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound"> 
<add-message-property key="http.headers.username" value="admin" /> 
<add-message-property key="http.headers.password" value="admin"/>
<add-message-property key="Accept" value="application/json"/>
</message-properties-transformer>

    <logger message=" custom header username and password.... ... #[message.inboundProperties.'http.headers'.username]   #[message.inboundProperties.'http.headers'.password]  " level="INFO" />
```

If I set header username and pasword in mule like this ,in log message it show null value . any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Use the following :-

```
<message-properties-transformer scope="outbound"> 
<add-message-property key="username" value="admin" /> 
<add-message-property key="password" value="password"/>
<add-message-property key="Accept" value="application/json"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
```

and retrieve using following:-

```
 <logger  message=" custom header username and password... #[message.outboundProperties['username']] and  #[message.outboundProperties['password']]"
        level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```